# How to be successful under a very very hot tempered & impatient boss?

Tags: management, intervention

I am incharge of a regional office and trying to set up a production unit for garments. I need more staff under me to carry out & maintain the office & production tasks.

My boss is a very impatient and short tempered person. He is the direct owner of the organization and I report to him. I keep employing new candidates. Every one of them take time to get oriented to the new environment before starting to give an effective contribution to take some work load off me.. But my boss gets very impatient and irritated with them. He expects the new comers to work efficiently from the first day, asks them to report to him every one hour. He speaks very fast and most of the time the newcomers don't get to understand him properly.. And when his temper goes up (which is most of the time), he does not care who is around and shouts at me (or anybody for that matter, whoever upset him). This scares the new comers more. They leave the job as quickly as they join. He blames me that no one is sticking around.

I am currently working for 15-16hrs a day, 7days a week and am still unable to satisfy this person (my boss) as I am doing the work of 5persons at a time. I am not getting enough support from new staff as they are never lasting for more than a month at the most.Please can someone guide me how to create an effective team?? (I have tried that the new joiners report to me and me in turn to my boss, but he never likes that as he says it delays the process and subsequently he calls them directly and gives instructions.)

Comment: With a boss like that, you are never going to assemble a team that he will like. I suggest you start looking for another job and let him deal with his own problems.

Comment: You're working at least 105 hours a week... I want you to think about it like this. Is your boss paying you 2.5 the normal salary for this job? Are you not worried about your life/work balance being totally shot? You realize even if you went directly from work to bed then back to work you're not getting the minimum "healthy" amount of sleep? You're basically working yourself to death. You need to ask yourself. Is this worth it? Is this what you want in life? If net, it's time to find a new job. Your boss's problems are not yours. Don't let his issues ruin your life.

Comment: Can you clarify some points in your question, please? Is your boss afraid of something? Is the business in serious trouble (beyond the trouble caused by high turnover of the employees you recruited)? Does he have something that triggers his rage? What relationship do you have with him that makes you work so hard to compensate for his bad behavior and rescue him?

Comment: Is 15-16hrs a day compatible with your idea of a career at this point in your life?

Answer (score 4):

First off

> I am currently working for 15-16hrs a day, 7 days a week

That is just insane! Stop doing that immediately. No salary and no job in the world are worth doing that.

I think your problem is not so much your boss but that you don't seem to distinguish between you, your boss and your company. What do you mean when you say "successful"? Do you want your company to be successful? Do you want to please you boss? Or do **you** want to be successful?

You are not your company and your company's problems aren't yours. Ask yourself what's best for *you* and *your* career and then go with that.

Answer (score 2):

> Am not getting enough support from new staff as they are never lasting
>   for more than a month at the most... Pls can someone guide me how to
>   create an effective team??

You should talk to your boss (when he is calm) and explain your difficulties in pulling together a good team.

Then you should get your boss directly involved in the interviewing/hiring process.

That way he can help choose candidates who won't leave when his hot temper appears.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, and I appreciate this is difficult, but the people who are leaving are doing the right thing and you should probably do the same thing if you cannot get this person to change.

People who are staying with this guy, including you, are teaching him that being bad tempered with employees all the time is ok. And it's not. It's not the right way to treat other people and it's bad for the business too.

If you are not doing so already, as the manager of the new staff you need to *tell him* (not allow it to turn into a 'discussion') that the reason people are leaving is because of his temper, and that he needs to respect you as a manager by going through you to speak to your staff and respect *whoever* he is speaking to by not raging at them over the slightest little thing or else you will leave.

And I would also (regardless of whether the reason for this is your boss or something you've just done yourself) start working more sensible hours. Quite aside from the impact on your life, it is again better for the business for its people to be well rested and have a break from the environment instead of being burnt out due to too much stress or overwork.

And then once you have told your boss all of this you need to stick to your guns even if that means you end up leaving. Whether things improve and you stay or things stay as they are and you leave then you will feel better for it, and I suspect the business itself will do better too.